# Generating PDF from Image iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext

I am attempting to generate a PDF of an image I currently have loaded into an image view. I think my code is correct but when I check the documents folder of the simulator nothing pops up. Any ideas?
Here is the code linked to my botton:

```
    @IBAction func saveToPdf(sender: AnyObject) {
    var fileName:String = "new.pdf"
    var rect =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 850, 1100)
    var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    var pdfPath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfPath, CGRectZero, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(rect, nil)
    var currentContext:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    imageView.image?.drawInRect(rect)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
}
```

Comment: I suggest you step through this code in the debugger and check: (1) is pdfPath what you expect (maybe you're looking in the wrong place in the finder), (2) imageView is not nil (possibly this is an IBOutlet that you forgot to hook up, and (3) imageView.image is not nil.

Comment: Found the problem, I was just looking in the wrong path for the simulator. Thx @AaronGolden!